# Java Subclass being brought in through classpath not able to find parent

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, classpath

For reasons outside the scope of this question I have two jars.

Jar1: `project/project.jar` which is a spring-boot jar and contains class A.

Jar2: `mock/project-mock.jar` which is a jar that contains class B.

`project-mock.jar` does not have a main class and is not meant to be ran standalone.

**Class B extends Class A.**

I'm trying to run these jars together using the following command

```
java -cp project/project.jar:mock/project-mock.jar org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

When I run the above command the spring boot jar starts initializing but then I get an exception:

```
 problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/project/Class A
```

Is this an issue relating to how I am trying to start the application or how do I fix the classpath issue to correctly set the jars on the same classpath?

Edit: I don't believe this is the same issue as [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java) since adding the two jars on the command line would put them on the same classpath, i thought. If that is not the case then that would be the issue but I would like to know why then so I can fix it.
Edit on the Edit: Looking further into the exception thrown there is a nested exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException which brings me back to the classpath issue rather than the class not correctly loading the first time.

Comment: "NoClassDefFoundError: com/project/Class A" - a class named `Class`? and what's that 'A'  separated by a blank in that message?

Comment: hmm I don't like the fact that I can't add the answer now that it has been marked a duplicate. Oh well, loss for the community.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch A bad example of sudo code. In this case it should have just been called A.